# PHP: injecting HTML into an if/else tag?

Tags: php

Here is the original script:

```
<?php
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $args = array(
            'redirect'          => site_url( '/index.php/portal ' ), 
            'form_id'           => 'loginform-custom',
            'label_username'    => __( 'Username' ),
            'label_password'    => __( 'Password' ),
            'label_remember'    => __( 'Remember Me' ),
            'label_log_in'      => __( 'Log in' ),
            'remember'          => true
        );
        wp_login_form( $args );
    } else {
        wp_loginout( index.php/portal() );
    }
?>
```

I wanted to inject some HTML into this if/else script so I cut it up like this but I'm unsure if I did it right. It works when I run it but I care more if it's done right (because even poorly-written code can unfortunately work).

And here is how I cut it up.

```
<?php
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $args = array(
            'redirect'          => site_url( '/index.php/portal ' ), 
            'form_id'           => 'loginform-custom',
            'label_username'    => __( 'Username' ),
            'label_password'    => __( 'Password' ),
            'label_remember'    => __( 'Remember Me' ),
            'label_log_in'      => __( 'Log in' ),
            'remember'          => true
        );
        wp_login_form( $args );
?>

<p>The portal is for registered users only.</p>

<?php
    } else {
        wp_loginout( index.php/portal() );
?>

<p>We recommend logging out after each session.</p>
<p><a href="/index.php/portal">Continue to portal</a></p>

<?php } ?>
```

So did I do it right?

Comment: Well... Does it work? Do you see your new paragraphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well-written as opposed to working but poorly written code is a distinct matter of opinion and taste. There are various [style guides](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) if you're interested in seeing examples.

Personally in your example above, I would change two things: indentation, and curly braces.

I find php open/closing tags in and html tags in templates to be hard to read when they are not lined up with the rest of the indentation:

```
<?php
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $args = array(
        'redirect'          => site_url( '/index.php/portal ' ), 
        'form_id'           => 'loginform-custom',
        'label_username'    => __( 'Username' ),
        'label_password'    => __( 'Password' ),
        'label_remember'    => __( 'Remember Me' ),
        'label_log_in'      => __( 'Log in' ),
        'remember'          => true
    );
    wp_login_form( $args );
    ?>

    <p>The portal is for registered users only.</p>

    <?php
} else {
    wp_loginout( index.php/portal() );
    ?>

    <p>We recommend logging out after each session.</p>
    <p><a href="/index.php/portal">Continue to portal</a></p>

<?php } ?>
```

This makes it much clearer what goes inside each if/else block. Along the same vein, I would replace the if/else curly braces with colons and endif tags, as well as move any php open/close tags onto the same lines as the php functionality.

```
<?php if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
    <?php 
    $args = array(
        'redirect'          => site_url( '/index.php/portal ' ), 
        'form_id'           => 'loginform-custom',
        'label_username'    => __( 'Username' ),
        'label_password'    => __( 'Password' ),
        'label_remember'    => __( 'Remember Me' ),
        'label_log_in'      => __( 'Log in' ),
        'remember'          => true
    );
    wp_login_form( $args ); ?>

    <p>The portal is for registered users only.</p>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php wp_loginout( index.php/portal() ); ?>

    <p>We recommend logging out after each session.</p>
    <p><a href="/index.php/portal">Continue to portal</a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This makes it easier to see which if/else/end blocks are related to each other, as well ask making it clear what functionality is php and what is HTML.

Multi-line php blocks are somewhat of a code smell to me, indicating logic that should be put in a function or class elsewhere and referenced in a single line in your template:

```
<?php 
# some other file, maybe have a modules/ or helpers/ directory in your plugin
# or theme that contains functions and classes that are used for functionality.
function 5south_custom_login_form() {
    $args = array(
        'redirect'          => site_url( '/index.php/portal ' ), 
        'form_id'           => 'loginform-custom',
        'label_username'    => __( 'Username' ),
        'label_password'    => __( 'Password' ),
        'label_remember'    => __( 'Remember Me' ),
        'label_log_in'      => __( 'Log in' ),
        'remember'          => true
    );
    wp_login_form( $args );
}

# your template file
<?php if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
    <?php 5south_custom_login_form() ?>

    <p>The portal is for registered users only.</p>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php wp_loginout( index.php/portal() ); ?>

    <p>We recommend logging out after each session.</p>
    <p><a href="/index.php/portal">Continue to portal</a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Generally I find that if there's more than 5-10 lines in a php `if` block in a template file, its usually worth breaking that functionality into a separate template and including it inside the `if` or `else` statement. This makes the template logic easier to follow.

If you find yourself nesting if/else statements in a complex way in a template file, it's probably time to reassess how the template file is loaded and perhaps create a function or functions to choose exact templates or partial templates for each specific situation.

Some people will see what I've done above and throw up in their mouth a little.